# Implicit function in an ODE when using DSolve

Tags: differential-equations, implicit

I'm trying to solve an ODE with DSolve. The problem I'm facing is that in the ODE there appears an implicit function of the variable r*. The equation I'm trying to solve is

```
-q''[r*] + (-2 (a/r^3) (1 - a/r)^3 - w^2) q[r*] == 0
```

with `a` and `w` parameters and `r*[r]=2 a Log[r-a]-a^2/(r-a)+r` (tortoise coördinate), which cannot be inverted such that I cannot write my ODE only in terms of `r*`. Is it possible to solve the equation by somehow using the implicit function relation?

Comment: `r*` means `r` times (whatever follows) in Mathematica.  It seems you mean it to be either a function like `rstar[r]` or a variable `rstar`. Ultimately, do you want `q` as a function of `r` or of `rstar`?  The latter should be theoretically possible if you write `r[rstar]` instead of `r` and use the implicit equation `rstar==2 a Log[r[rstar]-a]-a^2/(r[rstar]-a)+r[rstar]`. Probably `DSolve` can't solve it, I'd guess. But you could use `NDSolve` or `ParametricNDSolve` on numeric values for `a` and `w`.

Comment: You can use `Format[rstar] = Superscript["r", "*"];` to change the display of `rstar` in output.